# Creating js files from proto(golang)

Tags: node.js, go, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create a .js file from my .proto file, but whenever I run command such as

```
pbjs -t static-module -w commonjs -o output.js input.proto
```

on my vscode,it shows error like:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:269
throw err;
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'input.proto'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pbjs\cli.js:20:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'msg/input.proto'
}
```

my node.js version is v12.18.4 and npm version is 6.14.6

What i'm trying to get is the .js file of my proto file.
I'm new to this, would appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: The error suggests that `pbjs` is not finding a file called `input.proto` in the folder from which you're running the command. Is there a file called `input.proto` in the current directory?

Comment: Yes there is... so I'm quite confused...